# How to deploy spring-cloud-config server in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, spring-cloud-config

I've got a problem with my docker-compose. I'm trying to create mulitple containers with one spring-cloud-config-server, and im trying to use spring-cloud server with my webapps container.

That's the list of my containers:

- 1 for the BDD (db)
- 1 for spring cloud config server (configproperties)
- 1 for some webapps (webapps)
- 1 nginx for reverse proxying (cnginx)

I already try to use localhost, my config-server name as host in environment variable : SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI and in boostrap.properties.
My 'configproperties' container, use 8085 in the server.xml.

That's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  cnginx:
    image: cnginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - configproperties
      - cprocess
      - webapps
  db:
    image: postgres:9.3
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: xxx
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: xxx
    restart: always
    command:
      - -c
      - max_prepared_transactions=100
  configproperties:
    restart: on-failure:2
    image: configproperties
    depends_on:
      - db
    expose:
      - "8085"
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/mydbName?currentSchema=public
  webapps:
    restart: on-failure:2
    image: webapps
    links:
      - "configproperties"
    environment:
      - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://configproperties:8085/config-server
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    depends_on:
      - configproperties
    expose:
      - "8085"
```

When i run my docker-compose, my webapps are deploying with somme error like:
- Could not resolve placeholder 'repository.temps' in value "${repository.temps}"

But when i'm using postman and send a request like that :
 http://localhost/config-server/myApplication/docker/latest
It's working properly, the request return all configuration for 'myApplication'.

I think i have miss somethink, but i don't find it...

Anyone can help me ?

Regards,

Comment: There are some debugging suggestions. Comment out the webapps, then run the compose stack and login the configserver container to test if the host name with port 8085 working or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using springcloud server, we just need to run our webapps after the initialisation of the springcloud server.

```
#!/bin/bash

CONFIG_SERVER_URL=$SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI/myApp/production/latest

#Check si le le serveur de config est bien lancé
echo 'Waiting for tomcat to be available'
attempt_counter=0
max_attempts=10
while [[ "$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w ''%{http_code}'' $CONFIG_SERVER_URL)" != "200" ]]; do
    if [ ${attempt_counter} -eq ${max_attempts} ];then
        echo "Max attempts reached on $CONFIG_SERVER_URL"
        exit 1
    fi
    attempt_counter=$(($attempt_counter+1))
    echo "code retour $(curl -s -o /dev/null -w ''%{http_code}'' $CONFIG_SERVER_URL)"
    echo "Attempt to connect to $CONFIG_SERVER_URL : $attempt_counter/$max_attempts"
    sleep 15
done
echo 'Tomcat is available'
mv /usr/local/tomcat/webappsTmp/* /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```